# Can't copy or paste text in Cocoa after deleted edit menu item

Tags: cocoa, macos

I can't copy or paste any text on nstextfield after deleted edit menu item on Interface Builder. I've re-added edit menu item but still can't. Anyone know how to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reconnect the menu items to a target. In this case, connecting the `selector` property of the item to the First Responder's appropriate action method will do the trick.

Comment: Life saver, i had no clue why i can't paste anymore and thought is something about my cells, till i thought maybe i cannot paste anywhere in the app. Now it's 2015 and re-adding the edit menu adds the connections as well and just works

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the `cut:`, `copy:` and `paste:` messages to the First Responder from the "Sent Action" of the respective menu items.